# Express HTML patch form req.body is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm currently making a to-do list using Express and Node.js with MongoDB and Mongoose. I'm trying to update the to-do list so I've tried to use patch however this just changes the data to null. (No error messages shown but the HTTP status code is 400)

```js
router.patch('/:id', ensureAuth, async(req, res) => {
  try {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const updatedTask = await Task.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {
      task: req.body.taskbox
    })

    res.send(result);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({
      message: err.message
    })
  }
})
```

I'm thinking the error might be to do with the "req.body.taskbox" since console.log(req.body.taskbox) shows "undefined" and console.log(req.body) prints {}. Furthermore, when I hardcode something there, the patch works. (e.g. task: "Clean window" - this would update the task successfully to say "Clean window").

The code below shows where the HTML form is generated:

```js
static addTaskToTable(currentTask) {
  const list = document.querySelector('#task-list');
  const row = document.createElement('div');

  row.innerHTML = `
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <form id="task-form-for-${currentTask.taskId}">
                    <input type="text" name="taskbox" value="${currentTask.task}"  />
                    </form>
                </div>
            
                <div class="col">
                    <form id="edit-for-${currentTask.taskId}">
                        <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" value="edit" onclick="Store.editTask('${currentTask.taskId}')" /></p> 
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div class="col">
                    <form id="delete-form-for-${currentTask.taskId}">  
                        <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete" onclick="Store.deleteTask('${currentTask.taskId}')" value=" x " /></p>
                    </form>
                </div>
            
            </div>    
            `;

  list.appendChild(row);
}
```

I loop through the tasks in the database to display them using this function: (This *could* be another place that could've caused this error maybe?)

```js
    static displayTasks(){

        Store.getTasksArr().then(taskData => {

            let tasks = [];
            let i;

            taskData.map((currentTasks) => {
                tasks.push(currentTasks)
            })

            tasks.forEach((task) => UI.addTaskToTable(task));
        })        
    }
```

The fetch request:

```js
static editTask = async(id) => {

  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:5500/tasks/' + id, {
    method: "PATCH",
  });

  const json = await res.json();
  console.log(json);

}
```

My get, post, and delete all work fine and for the post, I wrote something very similar so I'm also confused as to why the patch doesn't retrieve the data from the textbox but in the post request it does:

```js
router.post('/', ensureAuth, async(req, res) => {
  try {
    const task = new Task({
      task: req.body.newtask,
      user: req.user.id
    })
    const newTask = await task.save()
    res.status(201)
    res.redirect('/home')
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({
      message: err.message
    })
  }
})
```

I also have a body-parser middleware already defined:

```js
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.json());
```

Comment: You are not passing the body here `const res = await fetch('http://localhost:5500/tasks/' + id, {
    method: "PATCH",
  });`

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath I think the body-parser middleware is what allows me to pass in the data from the forms using the req.body. This retrieved the data fine when I posted data.